# Data View : Unsubscribe and ListSubscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, unsubscriber, data-views

Is their a difference between the response if I query all from Data View "Unsubscribe" versus if I query all from "ListSubscribers" where status = Unsubscribed.

I am getting a very different count for my account when I run both these queries.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

The `_Unsubscribe` data view contains unsubscribe actions taken by the subscriber after receiving an email.  It's by `JobID`.

`_ListSubscriber` list status is the current status of the subscriber specific to the list.